# Do changes to the strings.xml file require compilation for the changes to take effect?

Tags: android, xml

I'm making an Android game and I would like some of the data to be specified via XML, specifically the `strings.xml` file. Would changes to the data found in the `strings.xml` file require that I compile the project again before the made changes take effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to your question is YES. This is due to you are referring those string in your xml files in form of `@String/somename` so this id must have to be available in your `R.java` file. Thus to reflect changes in your `R.java` file you must have to compile code and may be possible clean project to reflect changes

Comment: What if the id's don't change? Just the values?

Comment: then also my friend you have to build your project to reflect changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they do need compilation.

To save time set Build Automatically in your eclipse then whenever you save the code gets build automatically then and there. This will save a lot of time as all you need to press is Ctrl + S

Answer (score 1):

yes do need to compile again for all changes..